# Depth property not setting correct value in BST

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I wanted to add depth in all nodes in a Binary search tree. This is my Add method. But I see my depth property setting arbitrary value. Could someone please let me know what I'm making mistake.

```
public void Add(int data)
    {
        BNode current = root;
        int depth = 0;           
        while (true)
        {
            if (data < (int)current.Data && current.Left != null)
            {
                depth = depth + 1;
                current = current.Left;
            }
            else if (data < (int)current.Data && current.Left == null)
            {
                depth = depth + 1;
                current.Left = new BNode(data);
                current.Left.Parent = current;
                current.Depth = depth;
                break;
            }
            else if (data > (int)current.Data && current.Right != null)
            {
                depth = depth + 1;
               current = current.Right;
            }
            else if (data > (int)current.Data && current.Right == null)
            {
                depth = depth + 1;
                current.Right = new BNode(data);
                current.Right.Parent = current;
                current.Right.Depth = depth;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, I have findout my mistake.

Instead of

```
current.Depth = depth;
```

it should be

```
current.Left.Depth = depth;
```